# Is there an easier way to convert from QList<Class*> to QList<QPointer<Class>>?

Tags: c++, qt

I have several classes with attributes of the type `QList<ClassName *>`. I use raw pointers to signal ownership. An accessor for this would return `QList<QPointer<ClassName>>` since we don't want to hand out raw pointers. The problem is that at the moment every accessor more or less looks like the following:

```
QList<QPointer<ClassName>> values;
ClassName* value;
foreach(value, m_values){
    values.append(QPointer<ClassName>(value));
}
return values;
```

In some cases we use different containers than `QList` and sometimes the values in the containers are const. Now I wonder if there is a way that doesn't require me to copy/paste this to every accessor because it feels like either there should be a better way or we are doing something wrong in the first place.

Comment: Well, two thoughts: 1) I would rethink the API of such a class - is it really necessary to return the QList? Wouldn't it be better to ask the owner to act upon the elements or a certain element? Remember one of the principles of OOP: "tell, don't ask". 2) Why doesn't the owning class store the list of QPointers? Why raw pointers to express ownership, this seems weird to me. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Another thought, why provide the accessor at all?

Comment: @V.K. The owning class could store the list of `QPointer`s, but they are weak pointers, so it still needs to store the objects somewhere. So it'd need to have to members: as an owning collection, *and* a collection of `QPointer`s.

Comment: @KubaOber wouldn't setting the parent of the objects to the owning class be enough to store them? Shouldn't Qt take care of that?

Comment: Yes it would, and as I explain in my answer, you can simply use `QObject` to store a collection of other objects, and you get object trees for free :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use raw pointers to signal ownership.

Don't then. In C++11, use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, as appropriate. The Qt itself uses a `QObject` pointer without implying ownership. E.g. `QObject::children()` returns a `QObjectList = QList<QObject*>`. I think you're vastly overcomplicating things by using `QPointer`. To minimally affect other code, simply return `QObjectList`.

If the object list is constant (but not necessarily the objects themselves), you could create the accessible container once:

```
class MyClass {
  std::list<QObject> m_gadgets;
  QList<QPointer<QObject>> m_userGadgets; // or std::list<...>
public:
  typedef const std::list<QObject> Gadgets;
  MyClass() {
    m_gadgets.emplace_back(...);
    ...
    m_userGadgets.reserve(m_gadgets.size());
    for (auto & gadget : m_gadgets)
      m_userGadgets.push_back(QPointer(&gadget));
  }
  Gadgets & gadgets() const { return m_userGadgets; }
};
```

As you see, you don't need to use raw pointers to store `QObject`s. You can use e.g. `std::list` and emplacement, or `std::array`. This exposes the fragility of your API: it's very sensitive to the container you internally use.

It's often idiomatic to give access to containers through iterators. You could expose object containers via iterators, and the users should write code that only requires a particular black-box iterator type.

E.g.:

```
class MyClass {
  std::list<QObject> m_gadgets;
public:
  typedef std::list<QObject>::const_iterator GadgetsConstIterator;
  GadgetsConstIterator gadgetsBegin() const { return m_gadgets.begin(); }
  GadgetsConstIterator gadgetsEnd() const { return m_gadgets.end(); }
};

void gadgetsUser(MyClass::GadgetsConstIterator begin, MyClass::GadgetsConstIterator end);
```

This will work no matter what is the concrete type of `GadgetsConstIterator`, as long as it's of the same iterator category and the user makes no other unwarranted assumptions on the iterator.

You could also expose the object containers as a generic container, where the user should be instructed to use `std::begin(container)` and `std::end(container)` to access the container. That way you could even use raw C arrays (shudder):

```
class MyClass {
  QObject m_gadgets[5];
  // or
  std::array<QObject, 5> m_gadgets;
  // or
  std::list<QObject> m_gadgets;
public:
  // adjust as necessary
  typedef QObject Gadgets[5];
  typedef const QObject ConstGadgets[5];
  ConstGadgets & gadgets() const { return reinterpret_cast<ConstGadgets&>(m_gadgets); }
  Gadgets & gadgets() { return m_gadgets; }
}

void gadgetsUser1(MyClass::ConstGadgets & gadgets) {
  for (auto gadget : gadgets)
    qDebug() << gadget.metaObject()->className();
}

void gadgetsUser2(MyClass::ConstGadgets & gadgets) {
  for (auto it = std::begin(gadgets); it != std::end(gadgets); it++)
    qDebug() << gadget.metaObject()->className();
}
```

Finally, you could also completely hide the collection type, and only expose a baked `forEach` that goes through a container:

```
class MyClass {
  std::list<QObject> m_gadgets;
public:
  template <typename F> forEachGadget(F && fun) const { 
    for (auto const & gadget : m_gadget) fun(gadget);
  }
  template <typename F> forEachGadget(F && fun) { 
    for (auto & gadget : m_gadget) fun(gadget);
  }
};

void OtherClass::gadgetUser(MyClass & c) {
  c.forEachGadget([this](const QObject & gadget) { qDebug() << &gadget; }
}
```

There are many variations possible here, choose them according to what feels most natural. In all cases, though, the user code must not depend on the concrete container or iterator types that it receives to access the objects.

Finally, you shouldn't forget that `QObject` is-a `QObject` container. You might offer more flexibility by simply storing objects as children of a container object. That way you can return object lists and trees using the same container type:

```
class MyClass {
  QObject m_gadgets;
public:
  MyClass() {
    new QObject(&m_gadgets); // list element 1
    new QObject(&m_gadgets); // list element 2
  }
  const QObject & gadgets() const { return m_gadgets; }
}

void gadgetsUser(const QObject & gadgets) {
  for (auto gadget : gadgets.children()) { qDebug() << gadget; }
  // or, DFS of a tree
  for (auto gadget : gadgets.children()) {
    qDebug() << gadget;
    gadgetsUser(*gadget);
  }
  // or, BFS of a tree
  for (auto gadget : gadgets.children())
    qDebug() << gadget;
  for (auto gadget : gadgets.children())
    gadgetsUser(*gadget);
}
```

Note that a `QObject` keeps its children as an internal list with stable order. `QObject::children()` merely returns a reference to an internally held list of children, so it has a very small `O(1)` cost. Adding a child to an object appends the object to its internal list of children - although not documented, it has been the case since Qt 4.0 at least.

Comment: I needed a bit longer to digest the answer. I'm rather new to C++ and comming from Java it gets really confusing at times. I'll probably rework the design a bit so I don't have to do the conversion I needed in my question. Though I'm not sure if anything of this answer will make it into my solution it definitely helped to understand the issues.

Comment: @ralgrad You definitely should get a copy of the 4th edition of *The C++ Programming Language* by Strostrup; it covers C++11. Don't get any earlier one. And read at least half of it. C++ and Java have fundamentally different idioms with regards to object lifetimes and resource management, a Java way of thinking will end you up with very awkward and needlessly inefficient code. It's required reading. You might be surprised how simple modern C++ can be - often simpler than Java! Don't bother initially with those pre-C++11 idioms that are obsoleted or superceded by C++11.